# templates and string literals and UNICODE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, unicode, mfc

NEW: Thank you everyone who helped me with this!  The answer is marked below, and I've expanded on the answer with a functioning version in my question, below (q.v.):

---

I seem to be running into this situation a lot (while updating our string utilities library):

I need a way to have a template which works for both char and wchar_t, which uses various string-literals.  Currently I'm finding this challenging because I don't know how to have a compile-time way to alter string literals to be narrow or wide character.

For consideration, take the following TCHAR based function:

```
// quote the given string in-place using the given quote character
inline void MakeQuoted(CString & str, TCHAR chQuote = _T('"'))
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote)
        str.Format(_T("%c%s%c"), chQuote, str, chQuote);
}
```

I want to template it instead:

```
// quote the given string in-place using the given quote character
template <typename CSTRING_T, typename CHAR_T>
inline void MakeQuoted(CSTRING_T & str, CHAR_T chQuote = '"')
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote)
        str.Format("%c%s%c", chQuote, str, chQuote);
}
```

Immediately we have a problem with the two string literals ('"', and "%c%s%c").

If the above is invoked for CSTRING_T = CStringA, CHAR_T = char, then the above literals are fine.  But if it is invoked for CStringW and wchar_t, then I really need (L'"', and L"%c%c%c").

So I need some way to do something like:

```
template <typename CSTRING_T, typename CHAR_T>
inline void MakeQuoted(CSTRING_T & str, CHAR_T chQuote = Literal<CHAR_T>('"'))
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote)
        str.Format(Literal<CHAR_T>("%c%s%c"), chQuote, str, chQuote);
}
```

And that's where I am lost: What in the world can I do to make Literal(string-or-character-literal) that actually results in L"string" or "string" depending on CHAR_T?

Edit: There are over a hundred functions, many of them more complex with more string-literals in them, that need to be available both for narrow and wide strings.  Short of copying every such function and then editing each one to either be wide or narrow, surely there is a technique that would allow a single definition that varies by CHAR_T?

---

I'm giving the answer to the hybrid macro + template that Mark Ransom supplied, but I wanted to include a more complete solution (for anyone who cared), so here it is:

```
// we supply a few helper constructs to make templates easier to write
// this is sort of the dark underbelly of template writing
// to help make the c++ compiler slightly less obnoxious

// generates the narrow or wide character literal depending on T
// usage: LITERAL(charT, "literal text") or LITERAL(charT, 'c')
#define LITERAL(T,x) template_details::literal_traits<typename T>::choose(x, L##x)

namespace template_details {

    // Literal Traits uses template specialization to achieve templated narrow or wide character literals for templates
    // the idea came from me (Steven S. Wolf), and the implementation from Mark Ransom on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261673/templates-and-string-literals-and-unicode)
    template<typename T>
    struct literal_traits
    {
        typedef char char_type;
        static const char * choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide) { return narrow; }
        static char choose(const char narrow, const wchar_t wide) { return narrow; }
    };

    template<>
    struct literal_traits<wchar_t>
    {
        typedef wchar_t char_type;
        static const wchar_t * choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide) { return wide; }
        static wchar_t choose(const char narrow, const wchar_t wide) { return wide; }
    };

} // template_details
```

In addition, I created some helpers to make writing templates that utilized this concept in conjunction with CStringT<> a bit easier / nicer to read & comprehend:

```
// generates the correct CString type based on char_T
template <typename charT>
struct cstring_type
{
    //  typedef CStringT< charT, ATL::StrTraitATL< charT, ATL::ChTraitsCRT< charT > > > type;
    // generate a compile time error if we're invoked on a charT that doesn't make sense
};

template <>
struct cstring_type<char>
{
    typedef CStringA type;
};

template <>
struct cstring_type<wchar_t>
{
    typedef CStringW type;
};

#define CSTRINGTYPE(T) typename cstring_type<T>::type

// returns an instance of a CStringA or CStringW based on the given char_T
template <typename charT>
inline CSTRINGTYPE(charT) make_cstring(const charT * psz)
{
    return psz;
}

// generates the character type of a given CStringT<>
#define CSTRINGCHAR(T) typename T::XCHAR
```

With the above, it is possible to write templates which generate the correct CString variety based on CStringT<> or char/wchar_t arguments.  For example:

```
// quote the given string in-place using the given quote character
template <typename cstringT>
inline void MakeQuoted(cstringT & str, CSTRINGCHAR(cstringT) chQuote = LITERAL(CSTRINGCHAR(cstringT), '"'))
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote)
        str.Format(LITERAL(cstringT::XCHAR, "%c%s%c"), chQuote, str, chQuote);
}

// return a quoted version of the given string
template <typename cstringT>
inline cstringT GetQuoted(cstringT str, CSTRINGCHAR(cstringT) chQuote = LITERAL(CSTRINGCHAR(cstringT), '"'))
{
    MakeQuoted(str, chQuote);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I am aware that I can use function overloading to generate two definitions for MakeQuoted, instead of using a single template, at which point I don't need to worry about the literals (see below for @In silico's answer).   However, that seems silly given that I'm repeating all of the code verbatim just to supply two different sets of literals.  Surely there is some way to use metaprogramming to generate the correct literal (the type-dependent literal) on the fly?

Comment: @Mordachai:  Not using metaprogramming.  If there were, we could switch on strings, too.  Can you give an an example of some syntax you'd like to utilize to *use* this function?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case.  Templates generate code which varies based on the type-parameters supplied to the template.  What I'm looking for here is a literal that varies with the type supplied to it.  Maybe template specialization?!  It's like I want the compiler to do automatic type-promotion for string literals (think of a scalar argument, the template would work without effort because a scalar literal is automatically promoted to the appropriate type.  but not so for string literals).  :(

Comment: @Mordachai: The reason why you can't promote a `const char*` to a `const wchar_t*` or vice versa is because they are entirely different types as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Yes, agreed, they are.  Yet L"abc" and "abc" are the *source code*, even though they produce different compiler-output.  Just as any template function vary by argument type, producing different compiler-code, yet derive entirely from the same source-code exactly.  It is exactly this facility I am trying to find a way to invoke.  Sorry, I know what you guys are saying, and you're right - but I cannot escape the feeling that there may be a way to blend the preprocessor and templates to achieve Literal<type>(value) semantics. ;)

Comment: Pair programming in slow motion - I love it.

Comment: @Mark - sadly, I am and have been a solo programmer for my employer for about a year (and for the past 11 years, I've not had another programmer of even my caliber (let alone the cream of the crop).  So Stack Overflow is a great resource for questions that I just don't have the depth to answer. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept is to use a macro to generate both forms of the literal, `char` and `wchar_t`, then let a template function choose which one is appropriate for the context.

Remember that template functions don't actually generate any code until you have other code that makes a call to them. Most of the time this doesn't matter, but it would for a library.

This code is untested, but I believe it will work.

```
#define LITERAL(T,x) CString_traits<T>::choose(x, L##x)

template<typename T>
struct CString_traits
{
    typedef char char_type;
    static const char * choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide) { return narrow; }
    static char choose(char narrow, wchar_t wide) { return narrow; }
};

template<>
struct CString_traits<CStringW>
{
    typedef wchar_t char_type;
    static const wchar_t * choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide) { return wide; }
    static wchar_t choose(char narrow, wchar_t wide) { return wide; }
};

template <typename T>
inline void MakeQuoted(T & str, CString_traits<T>::char_type chQuote = LITERAL(T,'"'))
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote)
        str.Format(LITERAL(T,"%c%s%c"), chQuote, str, chQuote);
}
```

Comment: The main problem with this that I can see is if the caller wanted to replace chQuote- they'd have to be exposed to the LITCHAR macro, it's not terribly clean from that point of view.

Comment: @DeadMG, I don't see any way to avoid exposing the calling code to the macro. It's necessary to create both char and wchar_t forms of the literal simultaneously without repeating yourself.

Comment: I'm not a language purist by any means.  I want code that is highly usable, and this looks promising.  I'll give it a shot and see if I can make it work.  Having to live with one extra macro in a world of thousands (Win32 programming) is hardly a down-side at all.

Answer (score 1):

This piece is my own personal tiny little bit of genius.

```
#include <malloc.h>
template<typename to, int size> to* make_stack_temporary(const char(&lit)[size], to* memory = (to*)_alloca(sizeof(to)*size)) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        memory[i] = lit[i];
    return memory;
}
```

When you use alloca in a default argument, it's actually allocated off the *caller*'s stack, allowing you to return arrays without resorting to the heap. No dynamic allocation, no memory freeing. _alloca is a CRT function provided by MSVC, so I don't give any portability guarantees - but if you're using ATL that's likely no problem anyway. Of course, this also means that the pointer cannot be held past the calling function, but it should suffice for temporary uses like format strings. There are also some caveats to do with exception handling that you are unlikely to come across (check MSDN for details), and of course, it will only work for characters which have the same binary representation, which to my knowledge is every character you can put in a narrow string literal. I appreciate that this only solves a subset of the actual problems you may have encountered, but it's a far superior solution to that specific subset than the macro, or specifying every literal twice, etc.

You can also use the definitely uglier but more behaviourally consistent aggregate initialization.

```
template<typename T> some_type some_func() {
    static const T array[] = { 'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'l', 'i', 't', 'e', 'r', 'a', 'l', '\0' };
}
```

In C++0x with variadic templates, it may be possible for this solution to not suck. I'm CLOSE to a better solution which is C++03, but don't hold your breath.

Edit: You can do this, which imo is the best solution, still involves some messing around.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

struct something {
    static const char ref[];
};

const char something::ref[] = "";

template<int N, const char(*t_ref)[N], typename to> struct to_literal {
private:
    static to hidden[N];
public:
    to_literal() 
    : ref(hidden) {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            hidden[i] = (*t_ref)[i];
    }
    const to(&ref)[N];
};
template<int N, const char(*t_ref)[N], typename to> to to_literal<N, t_ref, to>::hidden[];

template<int N, const char(&ref)[N], typename to> const to* make_literal() {
    return to_literal<N, &ref, to>().ref;
}

int main() {
    std::wcout << make_literal<sizeof(something::ref), something::ref, wchar_t>();
    std::wcin.get();
}
```

You have to go through every literal and make it a static member of a struct, then reference it, but it works much better.

Comment: @Mordachai: I also think that the language is poor in this regard and could be vastly improved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use templates for something like this, considering there's only two ways to use `MakeQuoted()`. You can use function overloading for the same purpose:

```
inline void MakeQuoted(CStringA& str, char chQuote = '"') 
{ 
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote) 
        str.Format("%c%s%c", chQuote, str, chQuote); 
} 


inline void MakeQuoted(CStringW& str, wchar_t chQuote = L'"') 
{ 
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote) 
        str.Format(L"%c%s%c", chQuote, str, chQuote); 
}
```

Surely this is the easiest way to do it without having to use macros, assuming that's your reason for attempting a template-based solution with your string utilities library.

You can factor out common functionality for long and complicated functions:

```
template<typename CStrT, typename CharT>
inline void MakeQuotedImpl(CStrT& str, CharT chQuote,
    const CharT* literal)
{
    if (str.IsEmpty() || str[0] != chQuote) 
        str.Format(literal, chQuote, str, chQuote); 

}

inline void MakeQuoted(CStringA& str, char chQuote = '"') 
{ 
    MakeQuotedImpl(str, chQuote, "%c%s%c");
} 


inline void MakeQuoted(CStringW& str, wchar_t chQuote = L'"') 
{
    MakeQuotedImpl(str, chQuote, L"%c%s%c");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing at the moment.  It doesn't scale terribly well (we've over a hundred functions similar to the above).

Comment: @Mordachai: According to your comment to John Dibling's answer, it seems you want to create a library that can work with both `char` and `wchar_t` based strings within a single project, without regard to compiler settings. Unfortunately, there isn't much more you can do then - function overloading is the "easiest" way to do it for this particular case. I know the Windows API has two versions for every function that accepts a string (e.g. `CreateWindowA()` vs. `CreateWindowW()`).

Comment: @Mordachai: Note that you may not need to resort to function overloading for every function in your string utilities library. If you do have functions that can be "converted" to template functions without problems like these, then you can certainly do it for those functions.

Comment: I can use templates so long as there are no literals.  As soon as there is a literal, I have to resort to function overloading (or sometimes I can factor out a single template that templatizes all necessary arguments, and then create two other functions which are char/wchar_t, and supply the needed arguments & appropriate literals to the underlying template version)

Comment: @Mordachai: That may the best way to go about it, especially for longer, more complicated functions. See my edit.

Comment: You may be right that this is as good as it gets... I was/am still hoping that there is someone with the chops with metaprogramming to render a better technique, since surely this sort of thing must come up from time to time?

Comment: @Mordachai: Template metaprogramming deals with types, not literals, which is why it wasn't the first thing I tried out with your problem. I don't think metaprogramming can help with this situation. I actually haven't came across this problem until today, because my projects are either exclusively Unicode, or use functions that do not require literals (like the `<<` operators in `std::stringstream` instead of `CString::Format()`).

Comment: Maybe drifting off topic, but... how does << help you if you're trying to write: stream << '"' << argument << '"'?  Now I'm using a stream and insertion operators, but the fact of literals remains (i.e. they're right only if the underlying stream is supossed to be encoding narrow characters).

Comment: You shouldn't use all caps for non-macro parameters.

Comment: @Mordachai: What I meant is that in this specific case the reason why you have a literal is because it is needed for `CString::Format()` to know how to format the string. In this case, you could use `stream << chQuote << str << chQuote;` or something like that. Of course you won't be able to eliminate all literals this way, but for this function that's one way to do it.

Comment: @DeadMG - Again, the standards that have been set in Microsoft's code are not up for debate.  Popping up every few moments to make a stupid comment like that does nothing to solve the problems at hand, are entirely your opinion, and utterly beside the point.

Comment: @Mordachai: While DeadMG's comment was not relevant to your problem, it's certainly not a stupid comment. Only macros are in all-caps by convention in C++. Yes, Microsoft doesn't follow this convention 100% of the time, but that doesn't matter. I certainly don't follow all aspects of Microsoft conventions like Hungarian notation for type identification, but I do use CamelCase for classes and functions. What's more important is for you be consistent and not use 20 different styles within a project.

Comment: @Mordachai: Microsoft's mistake in calling their namespace ATL does not make it any smarter to name your template parameters in all caps. C++ has this convention for a reason, and it's way older than Microsoft. Observing it is plain common sense. What difference does it really make to you to be cstring_t instead of CSTRING_T, except that any other library or anysuch may well choose to #define CSTRING_T?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation. I have made 1 source-code file and a header-file (of course) which I exclude from building. Then created 2 other source-files which contain the original source via an #include directive. In one file I #define UNICODE (if not already defined) before the include. In the other file I #undef UNICODE (if defined). the source file contains a few static structures and a number of functions ,which are identical (in text) for both sets of char (not when compiled). If every function has either wchar_t or char as a parameter results this method in 2 sets of overloaded functions or 2 sets of differently named functions (depends on how the header file is written ,take tchar.h as example). Now both UNICODE and ANSI versions of the functions are available for an application and if the header-file is correctly written also default version for TCHAR. If you wish I can ellaborated on it ,just say so.

Comment: the wrapping trick can alse be used on a header file but take care for redefining or re-undefining UNICODE.

Comment: I thought about doing this.  I guess as long as you setup _T, TEXT, and UNICODE, it would be adequate to my needs.  But if you try to call things like _ttoi, or _tcscpy, etc., won't those be previously defined as either _mbs or str - don't the CRT headers use #pragma once?

Comment: I myself didn't use CRT routines but the WINDOWS API (to avoid multi-threading issues). But you should try it ,if it works you save yourself al lot of work and debugging. Make sure however not use pre-compiled headers because that will prevent this technique from working. Only for wrapping sources ,your other source can use pp.

Comment: I think #pragma once means that a header is include only once during compilation of one particular source ,there for i don't think you'll run into troubles.

Comment: I also submitted a question about this technique : "One source with multiple objects"

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want the `TEXT` MFC macro:

```
TCHAR* psz = TEXT("Hello, generic string");
```

Comment: If I've answered a question you didn't ask, let me know & I'll delete this

Comment: This works if what I need is a string that varies with the compiler settings, rather than with the type of string being processed.  This works for client code very well (the application source), but is not helpful for library code which is used on both narrow and wide strings within a single project irrespective of the compiler's UNICODE or MBCS build target.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so, if you really want to template this, I think the best thing I've been able to come up with is a templated class that stores your literals, based on [this discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/129457-initializing-std-basic_string-literals). Something like this:

```
template <typename T> class Literal;
template <> class Literal<char>
{
public:
    static const char Quote = '"';
};
template <> class Literal<wchar_t>
{
public:
    static const wchar_t Quote = L'"';
};
```

Then, you'd use `Literal<CHAR_T>::Quote` in your non-specialized but templated functions. Kinda messy, I guess, but it has the benefit of leaving your function logic unduplicated and gives you templated string literals.

Comment: Same answer as above: this varies by compiler-build-target, not by passed in string type.  I have projects that have to work with both narrow and wide character strings within the same build (legacy files that are narrow, and wide for Win32 APIs, etc.)

Comment: Thanks - I thought about doing this in general as a policy class.  It would work, so long as I was willing to put all sorts of arbitrary strings in it for consumption (I could put this in a details namespace just for that header...).

Answer (score -1):

You can use template partial specialization for MarkQuoted, and quote based on the type.